# Is it possible to measure the resistivity of something using A.C. Current and a capacitor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, experimental-technique

I've read that A.C. current "passes" through a capacitor. Is it possible to use this and measure the resistivity of the medium between the plates? Any sources or links would be appreciated.

Comment: If you use an AC current you are not measuring a resistivity but a complex impedance. You have to measure the magnitude and the phase of the current relative to the phase of the applied voltage. Instruments that can do this exist for all frequency ranges, they are, however, the most important for radio-frequencies. Here is an image of such an instrument, which is often called a Vector Network analyzer: http://about.keysight.com/en/newsroom/imagelibrary/library/RFNA_ZA_images/image003_high.jpg. Having said that, for low frequencies this can be done with far less complicated and expensive means.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multimeter you can do it easily. Think of the capacitor as three resistors in series: the first lead, the dielectric, and the other lead. Resistors in series add resistance to combine, so we will add those three:

$$R_{eq} = 2R_{leads} + R_{dielectric} $$

We can assume the leads to have a resistance of almost 0 since they conducting metals. So the equation becomes:

$$ R_{eq} = R_{dielectric}$$

Use a multimeter to measure the resistance and then use some algebra to find resistivity ($\rho$):

$$R = \frac {\rho l}{A} $$

Comment: The OP specified using AC current, so this isn't really an answer to the questions.

Comment: @garyp this technique works regardless of what current. The OP can just as well use an AC current and then from circuit theory get the resistance then use the resistance equation to find $\rho$.

Comment: Ok, but you can't use a multimeter then.  I suggest editing your answer to remove the technique that uses a multimeter to measure resistance.